# Emacs keylogger

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to implement a keylogger in Emacs (for my own, non-nefarious purposes).

It seems that I can reliably capture the last command through `real-last-command` in the `pre-command-hook`

So, I can do something like:

```
(setq keylog-list nil)

(defun my-keylogger-function ()
  (setq keylog-list (cons real-last-command keylog-list)))

(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'my-keylogger-function)
```

After a few movement commands, we get

```
keylog-list's value is
(describe-variable left-char left-char previous-line previous-line left-char eval-last-sexp)
```

However, I'm interested in capturing the arguments to these commands as well (e.g. the arguments to `left-char`, which will by default be `1` but may be different if prefix arguments are used.

Is there a way to access the args as well?  Something like `real-last-command-arglist`?

Comment: You are not satisfied with `C-h l`?

Comment: Not really, I'm keen to have timestamps as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you log the *last* (i.e. previous) command? If you log `this-command` instead, you can log `current-prefix-arg`, which corresponds to the prefix argument used.

Comment: Yep, that works.  I was using `real-last-command` because that's what the [keyfreq](https://github.com/dacap/keyfreq) package uses, but this is better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A keylogger is also built into emacs: (open-dribble-file).